# Download Formatted Excel Reports Using the Reports REST API

Tags: analytics, analytics-api

I need to Download Formatted Excel Reports Using the Reports REST API.

I read the following Document(Page No. 51) and Wrote c# code to get the Report.

**Document :** https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_analytics_rest_api.pdf

**C# Code :**

```
string restQuery = serviceUrl + "/services/data/v48.0/analytics/reports/" + reportId;
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, restQuery);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + oauthToken);
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"));
HttpResponseMessage response = queryClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
var byteResult = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
var len = byteResult.Result.Length;
File.WriteAllBytes($"{Configuration["InputFilePath"]}{fileName}", byteResult.Result);
```

The following is the screen from the Report i got as output,

[image]

I need only the details(column and data) need to remove the Metatadata from Report.

**Is there is any options in API to retrieve only the details ?**

If not i need to write extra c# code to remove the unnecessary data.

I can see a parameter "includeDetails" to exclude the details.

**likewise is there is any parameter to exclude the Metadata from Report ?**

**Example :**

```
string restQuery = serviceUrl + "/services/data/v48.0/analytics/reports/" + reportId +"?includeDetails=false";
```

Comment: Please include some more detail, such as what endpoint you are hitting.

Comment: the endpoint i am using is /services/data/v47.0/analytics/reports/{reportid}

Comment: Have you evaluated whether you can construct a SOQL query to run on the API to extract this raw data?